# What is the svn:mergeinfo equivalent for git?

Tags: git, svn, merge

I am missing clean mergeinformation in git:

- What commits (list including comments) have been merged by a commit
- What commits have NOT been merged by a commit.

How can I get those? In SVN there was very useful concept of mergeinfo.

Comment: Have you tried variations of `git log branch_point..merge_point` (or alternatively `git show` with a range)? AFAIK git has no concept of merging only a range of revisions from a branch (for that use e.g. `git cherry-pick`), so what `svn mergeinfo` does seems a little redundant in git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what situation you're trying to address.

- You can list the commits from branch `foo` that are not yet merged into branch `bar` using:

  ```
  git log bar..foo
  ```
- You can list all commits from any local branch that aren't merged into branch `bar` using:

  ```
  git log --branches --not bar
  ```
- If you want remote branches, use `--remotes`. See `git-rev-list(1)` for more variations.
- Perhaps this is what you want for seeing what commits were new since the common ancestor of both parents of a merge, although I don't think the question is clear:

  ```
  git log <merge-commit>^1...<merge-commit>^2
  ```
- You can see which commits are cherry-picked between two branches using `git cherry`.

Comment: Looks promising, can you double, whether a "Not" is missing?

Answer (score 1):

For full SVN branch merges Git equivalent is full Git branch merge (i.e. existence merge-commit with several parents).

For SVN cherry-pick there's no strict equivalent. But if you use `git cherry-pick` command, it preserves commit message. Personally I use this commit message to understand if the change is present in a certain branch.